# Replace index.html by other html file in Apache

Tags: angular, apache

Currently, I am using Angular 8 and I want to use another HTML file (e.g. index.dz.html) instead of the index.html in the Apache way when the URL has `brand=dz`. So I tried to add this mod_rewrite into the httpd.conf.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.html [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^brand=(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.%1.html? [NC,L]
```

As the result, I think it keeps using index.html instead of index.dz.html. Is there anything I did wrong for the apache code? Thank you.

Comment: Please try with following RewriteRule
`RewriteRule ^(.*)?brand=(.*) index.$1.html? [NC,L]`

Comment: As per RewriteRule [docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule), i think back-reference only matches in pattern part of RewriteCond, and you are trying to get back-reference from reg-ex part.

Comment: I tried to update the RewriteRule, but it still keeps using index.html instead of index.dz.html.